# In Vue JS, assign data from mounted()

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vue-component, dynamic-data

I try to  create **Highchart inside data()** and **from mounted()** try to assign **series for highchart**.
but I could not assign **series** from **mounted()**. It would be very helpful if anyone could help me in this issue. 
I want to put data in Highchart's **series** from vue js **mounted()**.

```
data () {
    return {

        colors: ['#3B97B2', '#67BC42', '#FF56DE', '#E6D605', '#BC36FE', '#000'],

        chartOptions: {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            scrollablePlotArea: {
                minWidth: 700,
                scrollPositionX: 1
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Balance Sheet'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '2019年1月', '2019年2月', '2019年3月', '2019年4月', '2019年5月', '2019年6月', 
                '2019年7月', '2019年8月', '2019年9月', '2019年10月', '2019年11月', '2019年12月',
                '2020年1月', '2020年2月', '2020年3月', '2020年4月', '2020年5月', '2020年6月', 
                '2020年7月', '2020年8月', '2020年9月', '2020年10月', '2020年11月', '2020年12月',
                '2021年1月', '2021年2月', '2021年3月', '2021年4月', '2021年5月', '2021年6月', 
                '2021年7月', '2021年8月', '2021年9月', '2021年10月', '2021年11月', '2021年12月'
            ],
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            tickWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Wind speed (m/s)'
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            opposite: true
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.0f}%</b><br/>',
            shared: true,
            split: true // Tooltip comment
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },

            series: []
        }
    }
},

methods: {
    setSeries() {
        this.$setData(function() {
            this.chartOptions.series[1] = this.bsData[100000000];
        });
    }
}

mounted () {
    this.setSeries();
}
```

> I am just a beginner in Vue.js and thus not good at explaining things.

Comment: Do you use `highcharts-vue` official wrapper? Ref: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You need to use arrow function inside mounted. The scope of `this` pointer is lost when you use normal `function`.

```
methods: {
    setSeries() {
        // Note the use of arrow function
        this.$setData(() => {
            this.chartOptions.series[1] = this.bsData[100000000];
        });
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you do not want to use arrow function, maintain reference to `this` pointer using closure:

```
methods: {
    setSeries() {
        // Maintain the closure
        const vm = this;

        this.$setData(function () {
            vm.chartOptions.series[1] = vm.bsData[100000000];
        });
    }
}
```

Further, **there are two more problems** with your code. The method `$setData` does not exist in Vue.js. You need to use `$set` method as [documented here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set). So your code would be:

```
methods: {
    setSeries() {

        this.$set(() => {
            this.chartOptions.series[1] = this.bsData[100000000];
        });
    }
}
```

Next, you should not need to use `$set` method directly. It is meant to be used in corner cases. Vue.js detects changes automatically using **getters** and **setters**. Read more about [array change detection here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection). For array, you must use wrapped methods or create new array each time.

So your final solution would be something like:

```
methods: {
    setSeries() {
        // Updating array data structure by creating new array instead of updating array by index.
        this.chartOptions.series = [this.chartOptions.series[0], this.bsData[100000000]];
    }
}
```

In summary you need to do three things:

1. Use arrow function to maintain `this` reference.
2. Do not use `$set` to change Vue instance data.
3. Do not mutate array directly using index. Use methods like `concat`, wrapped methods like `push`, `pop`, etc. or de-structuring to create new array.

Comment: What is $setData. Seeing it first tiem

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, you are right. It is `$set` and not `$setData`.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Thank you for you help. I have another. It is not working when i try to use the following instruction,       
 `this.chartOptions.series = [this.chartOptions.series[0], this.bsData[100000000]];`

Comment: @FatimaTahsina Try this: `this.chartOptions = { ...this.chartOptions, series: [this.chartOptions.series[0], this.bsData[100000000]] }'`. Also note that, you do not have `bsData` property defined on the component instance.